# Avoiding an indexing error in Python while looping

Tags: python, arrays, loops, sorting, alias

Regardless of whether this is the most efficient way to structure this sorting algorithm in Python (it's not), my understandings of indexing requirements/the nature of the built-in 'min' function are failing to account for the following error in the following code:

> Error: 
>   builtins.IndexError: list index out of range

Here's the code:

```
#Create function to sort arrays with numeric entries in increasing order
def selection_sort(arr):
  arruns = arr #pool of unsorted array values, initially the same as 'arr'
  indmin = 0 #initialize arbitrary value for indmin. 
  #indmin is the index of the minimum value of the entries in arruns
  for i in range(0,len(arr)): 
    if i > 0: #after the first looping cycle
      del arruns[indmin] #remove the entry that has been properly sorted 
      #from the pool of unsorted values.
    while arr[i] != min(arruns): 
      indmin = arruns.index(min(arruns)) #get index of min value in arruns
      arr[i] = arruns[indmin] 

#example case
x = [1,0,5,4] #simple array to be sorted
selection_sort(x)
print(x) #The expectation is: [0,1,4,5]
```

I've looked at a couple other index error examples and have not been able to attribute my problem to anything occurring while entering/exiting my while loop. I thought that my mapping of the sorting process was sound, but my code even fails on the simple array assigned to x above. Please help if able.

Comment: You are modifying your list as you iterate over it. `arruns = arr` does not copy `arr`, but now `arruns` references the same list as `arr`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`arr` and `arruns` are the same lists. You are removing items from the list, decreasing its size, but leaving max value of `i` variable untouched.

Fix:

```
arruns = [] + arr
```

This will create new array for `arruns`

Comment: Probably more idiomatic is `list(arr)` or `arr[:]`

Comment: Yes, it will be more "pythonic".

Comment: or doing it explicitly: `list.copy()`? :)

Comment: @MSeifert yeah, but that is only available in Python 2. I agree it's better from a readability perspective, but sometimes things just become the conventional way of doing it, and if you are going to be reading a lot of Python code, you better be able to pick up on what it's doing.

Comment: Yo the internet is great, thank you guys. MATLAB doesn't have the same alias functionality.